# Parse.com Hosting deploy crash while accessing Config in main.js

Tags: parse-platform, deployment, hosting, config, startup

While accessing to Parse.Config at hosted-code startup (parse deploy) I get this stacktrace:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'request'
   at Object.Parse._ajax (<anonymous>:654:17)
   at null.<anonymous> (Parse.js:1:18442)
   at e (Parse.js:2:8941)
   at Parse.js:2:9694
   at g (Parse.js:2:9431)
   at c.extend.then (Parse.js:2:9679)
   at Object.b._request (Parse.js:1:18277)
   at Function.b.Config.get (Parse.js:1:24017)
   at main.js:2:14
```

the code (in cloud/main.js) is:

```
Parse.initialize(applicationid,javascriptkey);
Parse.Config.get().then(
    function (_config){
        config = _config;
        console.log('Configuration init completed');
    }, function (_error){
        console.log('Failed loading configuration');
    });
// status function
Parse.Cloud.define("status", function(request, response) {
  response.success("spike@digitalx tracker up and running!");
});
```

seems that Config.get is trying to invoke "request" on any object.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Getting a similar problem myself. Makes 0 sense.